# See what affects wakeup time

Tags: login, suspend, login-screen, wakeup

Is there a way to check what affects startup time from suspend? I get this short black screen for ca. 5 seconds after waking from suspend, and then the login screen becomes visible. This does not happen on a fresh install, I tried to check after I installed each program, but I could never find the source.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see what gets run to Hibernste/Wake/Suspend/Resume. Investigate these shell scripts.

Comment: It says no manual entry for pm-action

Comment: See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/pm-action.8.html